# Get every item in a list that contains every string in an other list

Tags: c#, linq

I have basically two string-lists and want to get the elements of the first list that contain every word of the second list.

```
List<Sentence> sentences = new List<Sentence> { many elements };

List<string> keyWords= new List<string>{"cat", "the", "house"};

class Sentence 
{
public string shortname {get; set; }
}
```

Now, how do I perform a contain-check for every element of the keyWords-List for a sentence? Something like

```
var found = sentences.Where(x => x.shortname.ContainsAll(keyWords)));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var found = sentences.Where(x=> keyWords.All(y => x.shortname.Contains(y)));
```

The `All` method is used to filter out those sentences which contain all keywords from the list of keywords.

Answer (score 1):

Use [All](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548541(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
sentences.Where(x => keywords.All(k => x.shortname.Contains(k)));
```

If you find this to be a common search, you could create your own extension method

```
public static bool ContainsAll<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src, IEnumerable<T> target)
{
    return target.All(x => src.Contains(x));
}
```

This would allow you to write the code as you originall expressed it

```
sentences.Where(x => x.shortname.ContainsAll(keywords));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sentences.Where(s => keyWords.All(kw => s.shortname.Contains(kw)));
```

Use All, it returns true only if all elements in the sequence satisfy the condition